# setAnimation() method behaves like startAnimation() in Android

Tags: android, xml, animation

In the code below, the animation starts automatically even though I don't want it.

```
anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_anim);
imageview.setAnimation(anim);
```

I tried two more things and found out when the problem occurs.

The code below starts the animation whenever it is executed.

```
imageview.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_anim));
```

However the code below doesn't start the animation anymore after the first execution.

```
imageview.clearAnimation();
imageview.setAnimation(anim);
```

When a 'new animation instance' is set for the first time, the setAnimation() method activates just like the startAnimation() method, I guess.

Am I right?

I want to set an animation in advance and play it when I want to.

How can I do it??

Comment: set animation is starting the animation.If you want to start animation on button click or any other method then put the start animation line in that method.

Comment: So, there's no solution or any other ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes, you have to put this line " imageview.setAnimation(anim); " whenever you want to start the animation.

Comment: Hmm... That means there's no difference between setAninmation() and startAnimation().. Thanx

Comment: @Jenix setAnimation() is used when u want to add multiple animations to a view programmatically , you will be adding all animations to AnimationSet object